# Django Site numpy out of date?

Tags: python, django, numpy

I'm getting this error out of no where! I am assuming my numpy is out of date but pip won't let me help. Any suggestions? Here is my Traceback:

```
Environment:


Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/

Django Version: 1.7.3
Python Version: 2.7.5
Installed Applications:
('django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.sites',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'django.contrib.admin',
 'debug_toolbar',
 'hydro',
 'djcelery')
Installed Middleware:
('debug_toolbar.middleware.DebugToolbarMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware')


Traceback:
File "C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.2\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in get_response
  98.                 resolver_match = resolver.resolve(request.path_info)
File "C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.2\lib\site-packages\django\core\urlresolvers.py" in resolve
  343.             for pattern in self.url_patterns:
File "C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.2\lib\site-packages\django\core\urlresolvers.py" in url_patterns
  372.         patterns = getattr(self.urlconf_module, "urlpatterns", self.urlconf_module)
File "C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.2\lib\site-packages\django\core\urlresolvers.py" in urlconf_module
  366.             self._urlconf_module = import_module(self.urlconf_name)
File "C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.2\lib\importlib\__init__.py" in import_module
  37.     __import__(name)
File "C:\Users\kacalica\Desktop\Projects\hydroinformatics\Hydroinformatics\urls.py" in <module>
  6. from hydro import urls
File "C:\Users\kacalica\Desktop\Projects\hydroinformatics\hydro\urls.py" in <module>
  6. from hydro import views
File "C:\Users\kacalica\Desktop\Projects\hydroinformatics\hydro\views.py" in <module>
  2. from matplotlib import pylab
File "C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.2\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\__init__.py" in <module>
  180. from matplotlib.cbook import is_string_like
File "C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.2\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\cbook.py" in <module>
  33. import numpy as np
File "C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.2\lib\site-packages\numpy\__init__.py" in <module>
  137.     import add_newdocs
File "C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.2\lib\site-packages\numpy\add_newdocs.py" in <module>
  13. from numpy.lib import add_newdoc
File "C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.2\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\__init__.py" in <module>
  4. from type_check import *
File "C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.2\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\type_check.py" in <module>
  8. import numpy.core.numeric as _nx
File "C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.2\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\__init__.py" in <module>
  10. import numeric
File "C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.2\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\numeric.py" in <module>
  1356. from arrayprint import array2string, get_printoptions, set_printoptions
File "C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.2\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\arrayprint.py" in <module>
  20. from . import numerictypes as _nt

Exception Type: ImportError at /
Exception Value: cannot import name numerictypes
```

I think it needs an update because it points to numpy's core. And obviously I didn't write that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to re-download matplotlib (which includes numpy)

during my installation I had a zombie process that was using numpy and had to be killed before I could update the libraries. After that it worked!